# Compare Two Dates as Integers, Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a way to compare two dates in a SQL query, where dates are stored as integers in separate columns, as `year`, `month`, and `day`. (Please note that this wasn't my choice!) If the date was October 12th, 2011, for example, you'd have values of `2011`, `11`, and `12`, respectively.

My original stab at it was to do it arithmatically; this however sort of fell through when I realised that I will not know which of the two dates will be greater. I've tried to look into date support in SQL, but unfortunately I haven't really found anything that helps me out. I've found a few ways to convert to date formats in other flavours, such as MySQL, but nothing for Oracle's implementation.

Comment: What are you comparing for? Is it in an ORDER BY clause, or are you doing some sort of arithmetic on them?

Comment: What if you concat the 3 fields as yearmonthday (i.e. 20110302), cast to int and then do the comparison arithmetically?

Comment: I want to select pairs of X where the dates associated with those X are within Y years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your columns are called something like day, mon and year in table xyz

```
select to_date(to_char(day)||to_char(mon)||to_char(year),'ddmmyyyy')
from xyz
```

will convert the numbers to a date. You can then manipulate them as you wish.

Added in response to comment :

Probably the easiest way to exclude combinations of dd mon and yyyy that wouldn't convert to dates, would be to do the to_date in pl/sql, then have an invalid_date exception handler to trap problem combinations. If you have to use sql, I suppose you could try and exclude the invalid combinations before doing the to_date, so something like

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(day)||to_char(mon)||to_char(year),'ddmmyyyy')
FROM   xyz
WHERE  to_char(day)||to_char(mon) NOT IN ('3002','3102','3104','3106','3109','3111')
AND    (to_char(day)||to_char(mon) != '2902'
    OR to_char(year) IN (2008,2004,1996,1992,1988,...))
```

The ... would need to hold as many leap years as your data.

Comment: Would this work in the case where the year is not necessarily four digits long? I'm getting an error that reads: "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month". I just checked and all of my dates are valid, yet some have years with as low as a single digit.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the data, but are you sure you don't have any dates like 31st of September, or 30th of February ? that is what I would associate that error with at first glance.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought my quick glance was good enough, but upon further review I do have some dates such as Feburary 30th. I can't change this data at all, am I hosed?

Comment: If you allow invalid dates in your data, then you can write a function to validate a date when you retrieve it, otherwise ignore that row. A sample validation function can be found here: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/144534/2/

Comment: This answer is close, but not quite there. You are going to have problems with single digit day or year values, for example Jan 1, 2012 is going to be '112012', or the eleventh day of the twentieth month.

Comment: Either use a delimiter like `to_date(to_char(day)||'-'||to_char(mon)||'-'||to_char(year), 'dd-mm-yyyy')` or pad the day & month: `select to_date(lpad(to_char(1), 2, '0')||lpad(to_char(1), 2, '0')||to_char(2011), 'ddmmyyyy') from dual;`

Answer (score 0):

> Would this work in the case where the year is not necessarily four digits long?

If you have two character years ("98" for 1998, "02" for 2002) then you can use the RR year format, which will intelligently convert those. It will also correctly handle four digit years if both types happen to be intermingled.

examples:

select to_date(to_char(02)||'-'||to_char(12)||'-'||to_char(30),'RR-MM-DD')  from dual;

select to_date(to_char(1998)||'-'||to_char(12)||'-'||to_char(30),'RR-MM-DD')  from dual;